# How can I get the length of an array in a nested JSON object returned by Python requests?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I'm trying to port some code from Perl to Python. The code performs an HTTP GET request with non-default headers. The response is a JSON document. The top level element is an object that has a key named `queryResponse`. The value of that element is also an object, and it has a key named `entity`. The value of that element is an array. I want the number of elements in that array.

Here's the Perl Code:

```
my ($first, $max, $count) = (0, 1000, 1000);

while ($count == $max) {
  my $debugFlag = 1;
  my $uri = "/webacs/api/v2/data/Devices.json?.full=true&.nocount=true&" .
            ".firstResult=$first&.maxResults=$max";
  $piConnection->GET($uri, $headers);
  my $response = decode_json $piConnection->responseContent();
  $first = $first + 1000;
  $count = scalar @{$response->{queryResponse}{entity}};
```

And here's what I have so far in Python:

```
firstResult = 0
maxResults = 1000
count = 1000

while count == maxResults:
    test_urn = (URL + '/webacs/api/v2/data/Devices?.full=True&.nocount=True&.maxResults=%d&.firstResult=%d') % (maxResults, firstResult)
    get_response = requests.get(test_urn, verify=False)
    firstResult = firstResult + 1000
    count = len(get_response['queryResponse']) # This is the line I need help with
    print get_response.text
```

The part I'm having trouble with is getting the length of the array in the JSON response. How can I do this?

Comment: Two suggestions to get you more responses: (1) post working code, so we can reproduce your partial results and test our solutions (this includes defining the variable, **URL**); (2) describe the functionality you want, so non-Perl programmers can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use JSON::XS qw( decode_json );
my $response_json = '{ "queryResponse": { "entity": [ "a", "b", "c" ] } }';
my $response = decode_json($response_json);
my $count = @{ $response->{queryResponse}{entity} };
```

is equivalent to

```
import json
response_json = '{ "queryResponse": { "entity": [ "a", "b", "c" ] } }'
response = json.loads(response_json)
count = len(response['queryResponse']['entity'])
```

except perhaps in how errors are handled.

---

`response_json` is obtained from `get_response.text`.
`response` can be obtained from `get_response.json()` or as shown.

Comment: And requests has a [shortcut](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) for decoding a JSON response, so the OP could just do `response = requests.get(...)` followed by `count = len(response.json()['queryResponse']['entity'])`

Comment: I get the following error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "primeapi.py", line 48, in <module>
    count = len(get_response['queryResponse']['entity
TypeError: 'Response' object is unsubscriptable

Comment: Like I said, how errors are handled may vary. Since you're the python programmer and this is my second python program ever, I'll let you handle that.